# Why does the bandwidth measured by iperf through an ssh tunnel faster than the host machine's native network

Tags: linux, networking

I am running a simple bandwidth test between two machine using iperf, I am wondering why ssh tunnel is faster than host machine's native network.

**ssh tunnl**
execute `iperf3 -s` on 100.73.10.38(k8snode2)

```
[hanweisen@k8snode2 ~]$ iperf3 -s
-----------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on 5201
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

create ssh proxy on 100.73.10.37(k8snode1)

```
 [hanweisen@k8snode1 ~]$ ssh -NL :100.73.10.38:5201
 hanweisen@100.73.10.38
 SSH warning: Authorized users only. All activity may be monitored
 and reported.
 hanweisen@100.73.10.38's password:
```

then execute `iperf3 -c 127.0.0.1 -p 10800 -b 1600M -i 1 -t 10 -l 300` on 100.73.10.37:

```
 [hanweisen@k8snode1 ~]$ sudo iperf3 -c 127.0.0.1 -p 10800 -b 1600M -i 1 -t 10 -l 300
 Connecting to host 127.0.0.1, port 10800
 [  4] local 127.0.0.1 port 53678 connected to 127.0.0.1 port 10800
 [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr  Cwnd
 [  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   121 MBytes  1.02 Gbits/sec    0    639 KBytes
 [  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   122 MBytes  1.03 Gbits/sec    0    639 KBytes
 [  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   117 MBytes   984 Mbits/sec    0    639 KBytes
 [  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   117 MBytes   978 Mbits/sec    0    639 KBytes
 [  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   114 MBytes   957 Mbits/sec    0   2.62 MBytes
 [  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   102 MBytes   853 Mbits/sec    0   2.62 MBytes
 [  4]   6.00-7.00   sec   104 MBytes   873 Mbits/sec    0   2.62 MBytes
 [  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   105 MBytes   879 Mbits/sec    0   2.62 MBytes
 [  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   106 MBytes   893 Mbits/sec    0   2.62 MBytes
 [  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  98.0 MBytes   822 Mbits/sec    0   2.62 MBytes
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
 [  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.08 GBytes   928 Mbits/sec    0             sender
 [  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.00 GBytes   859 Mbits/sec                  receiver

 iperf Done.
```

the result on server(100.73.10.38) is:

```
 Accepted connection from 100.73.10.38, port 22468
 [  5] local 100.73.10.38 port 5201 connected to 100.73.10.38 port 22470
 [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
 [  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  91.9 MBytes   771 Mbits/sec
 [  5]   1.00-2.00   sec   106 MBytes   893 Mbits/sec
 [  5]   2.00-3.00   sec   104 MBytes   873 Mbits/sec
 [  5]   3.00-4.00   sec   105 MBytes   881 Mbits/sec
 [  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  98.3 MBytes   825 Mbits/sec
 [  5]   5.00-6.00   sec   100 MBytes   842 Mbits/sec
 [  5]   6.00-7.00   sec   103 MBytes   863 Mbits/sec
 [  5]   7.00-8.00   sec   105 MBytes   879 Mbits/sec
 [  5]   8.00-9.00   sec   102 MBytes   852 Mbits/sec
 [  5]   9.00-10.00  sec   104 MBytes   870 Mbits/sec
 [  5]  10.00-10.06  sec  4.91 MBytes   729 Mbits/sec
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
 [  5]   0.00-10.06  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  sender
 [  5]   0.00-10.06  sec  1.00 GBytes   854 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

**machine network**
execute `iperf3 -s` on 100.73.10.38(k8snode2)

```
[hanweisen@k8snode2 ~]$ iperf3 -s
-----------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on 5201
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

then execute `iperf3 -c 100.73.10.38 -b 1600M -i 1 -t 10 -l 300` on 100.73.10.37(k8snode1)

```
[hanweisen@k8snode1 ~]$ iperf3 -c 100.73.10.38 -b 1600M -i 1 -t 10 -l 300
Connecting to host 100.73.10.38, port 5201
[  4] local 100.73.10.37 port 37542 connected to 100.73.10.38 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr  Cwnd
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  67.1 MBytes   563 Mbits/sec    0   42.4 KBytes
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  70.0 MBytes   587 Mbits/sec    2   63.6 KBytes
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  70.3 MBytes   590 Mbits/sec    0   69.3 KBytes
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec  69.2 MBytes   581 Mbits/sec    0   73.5 KBytes
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  69.3 MBytes   582 Mbits/sec    0   73.5 KBytes
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  69.5 MBytes   583 Mbits/sec    6   73.5 KBytes
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  69.0 MBytes   579 Mbits/sec    2   73.5 KBytes
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  68.0 MBytes   570 Mbits/sec    0   73.5 KBytes
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  68.7 MBytes   576 Mbits/sec    0   73.5 KBytes
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  70.0 MBytes   588 Mbits/sec    3   73.5 KBytes
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   691 MBytes   580 Mbits/sec   13             sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   686 MBytes   576 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

the result on server(100.73.10.38) is:

```
Accepted connection from 100.73.10.37, port 37540
[  5] local 100.73.10.38 port 5201 connected to 100.73.10.37 port 37542
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  62.1 MBytes   521 Mbits/sec
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  63.1 MBytes   529 Mbits/sec
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  73.6 MBytes   618 Mbits/sec
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  74.1 MBytes   622 Mbits/sec
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  52.5 MBytes   440 Mbits/sec
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  79.0 MBytes   663 Mbits/sec
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  74.1 MBytes   622 Mbits/sec
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  57.3 MBytes   481 Mbits/sec
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  68.7 MBytes   576 Mbits/sec
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  78.5 MBytes   659 Mbits/sec
[  5]  10.00-10.04  sec  3.22 MBytes   658 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-10.04  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  sender
[  5]   0.00-10.04  sec   686 MBytes   573 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Comment: I don't see such a significant difference in my network. What if you try udp (so just `iperf3 -c client-ip -u` no other arguments)

Comment: Possibly compression? Try with using random data rather than the default very compressible patterns used by iperf. Check the ssh_config sshd_config settings for `Compression`.

Comment: I set the 'Compression' option in sshd_config to 'no', but the result is still the same.